# Column Name when using @ManyToOne

Tags: java, hibernate

When I am using `@OneToMany`/`@ManyToOne` Hibernate assumes the column name is 'task_id'.
Is there an Annotiation to tell Hibernate that the Column name is e.g. 'xxx'?

Table schema:

```
Project      Task
-------      ----
id           id
text         text
             project
```

Code:

```
class Project {
    ...
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "task")
    private List<Task> tasks;
}

class Task {
    ...
    @ManyToOne
    private Project project;
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's called ... `@JoinColumn`. Used as such:

```
@JoinColumn(name = "xxx")
```

You would use it on the owning side of the relationship (`Task`).

Comment: The dangers of skimming through as question. Thanks for the catch ... and I upvoted your answer as well.

Answer (score 2):

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="xxx")
private Project project;
```

From Jpa 2.0 specification, the declaration of `JoinColumn` interface

```
@Target({METHOD, FIELD}) @Retention(RUNTIME)
  public @interface JoinColumn {
  String name() default "";
  String referencedColumnName() default "";
  boolean unique() default false;
  boolean nullable() default true;
  boolean insertable() default true;
  boolean updatable() default true;
  String columnDefinition() default "";
  String table() default "";
}
```